# How to increase font size of displayname titles when it comes to JSON formating?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting

With SharePoint Online, is there a way for us to increase the font size of the `displayname` titles that we incorporate with JSON? For instance, here is my JSON formatting on a specific list...

[image]

As you can see, I want the displayname (only) to have a bumped up font size of 2rem, so the that title has great visibility compared to the section field items.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no formatting options available for the form body. The only options are the sections, their names, and the fields for each as you've already got.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to improve the experience when coding about the JSON in the form body, it may be better for you to post the idea in [user voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/). And I am not sure if there is a 3rd party tool available having this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the direct link. I put in my idea.